# AWS api gateway not working same after Deploying API

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have deployed a basic AWS API, Below are the screen shots.

[image]

now when i run Test from above and pass parameter shown in Query String of Method Request i will get the following response.

```
Request: /searchpatents?name=fsf&test=sfsf
```

Response against above request

```
{
  "name": "fsf",
  "sample": "sfsf",
  "controller": "awsapi",
  "action": "index",
  "awsapi": {
    "name": "fsf",
    "sample": "sfsf"
  }
}
```

Which shows that i can use the name and sample parameter on my HTTP endpoint.

Now i have deployed this api by clicking Deploy API button and sends HTTP request via curl and by POSTMAN after exporting it from AWS stage panel, I am not receiving name and test params.

[image]

My Integration Request is as below

[image]

Comment: A couple of things that standout: 1) why is your Postman request quoting the parameters? 2) you are making a GET request with a body which is non-standard. Why aren't you using POST or PUT?

Comment: I have tried without quotes that doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Making a GET request with a body is non-standard, and API Gateway is ignoring the body in a GET request. Please try to using POST/PUT for a request with a body.

Comment: GET request with URL query is not non standard rather it's very common and it's working in Sandbox that AWS provide issue is that sandbox in production working differently.